# Marshaling a JSON Patch payload into a struct - rfc7396

Tags: json, go

So I am trying to implement a simple version of Merge Patch JSON (rfc7396). This means that in my incoming json payload that some fields can a) have a value  b) have a null value (in which case they need to be nullified in the server db) c) be omitted from the json.

```
payload: {
 a:"some value"
 b: null
}
```

```
type SomeStruct struct {
    A     *string `json:"a,omitempty"`
    B     *string `json:"b,omitempty"`
    C     *string `json:"c,omitempty"`
}
```

so for fields b and c, when I unmarshal the json into the struct, both will be `<nil>`.

This is obviously confusing when I need to work out how to update my db columns - as the intention is that column b is supposed to be changed to null and column c is supposed to be left alone

Just wondering what the proper way to do this is in Go.
In Node a field could be undefined, null or have a value which was slightly easier.

Comment: Consider unmarshaling into a `map[string]*string` rather than a struct, e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/9-8YlLzOnfO. If you're using a struct, I don't see how you can get around the problem you identified without lots of extra logic, and this has nothing to do with unmarshaling. Putting JSON aside, how would you possibly create an instance of `SomeStruct` (or something like it) that conveys that intention of ignoring some fields and nulling out others?

Comment: yeah I hear you :) oh, just noticed your example

Comment: If you don't feel like using maps, you can declare custom types and have them implement the json unmarshaler interface https://play.golang.org/p/0qywduUCZSx. The unmarshaler implementation is very simple and JSON does not have too many types so implementing a few basic types coupled with conversion (as demonstrated in that example with `Int64`) should cover most of your needs.

Comment: So I decided to use the special custom types in my DTO (with IsNull , ISPresent etc), it seems to work nice. However, when I use those same DTOs for returning JSON responses in GET's, then I get ugly responses, do I need to do some reverse login in MarshalJSON() ?